# What do you use if you wish to install an Erlang library?

Tags: erlang

Do you use CEAN, copy the source and compile them, copy the BEAM files, or something else. I need to distribute some Erlang code and I'm not sure which to choose.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've been working on EPM, an Erlang package manager. It pulls from GitHub. It's non-invasive and doesn't require installing anything on your system other than downloading an escript. It works as follows:

```
jvorreuter$ ./epm install ibrowse mochiweb
epm v0.1.0, 2010

===============================
Install the following packages?
===============================
    + epm-mochiweb-master
    + cmullaparthi-ibrowse-master

([y]/n) y

+ downloading http://github.com/epm/mochiweb/tarball/master
+ running mochiweb build command
+ running mochiweb install command
+ downloading http://github.com/cmullaparthi/ibrowse/tarball/master
+ running ibrowse build command
+ running ibrowse install command
```

You can read more about it at http://www.jkvor.com/erlang-package-manager

**The linked blog post is blank as of August 2013.  The GitHub repository is at https://github.com/JacobVorreuter/epm**

Comment: Ok, this looks like it may have the most promise! And I could never get Faxian to work.

Comment: I couldn't find the archive to download though, can you send me the link, as that is what I would call an easy install. Download it, run it, and give it the ability to be self updating, like gem is

Comment: It is enough to do "wget -O ~/bin/epm http://github.com/JacobVorreuter/epm/raw/master/epm; chmod +x ~/bin/epm" and make sure ~/bin/epm is in your path

Comment: Just curious what problems people have had with using faxien?

Answer (score 4):

I clone the git repository, build it, and add the directory to my `ERL_LIBS` path. I hack the source for my private customizations. For those commits that are sensible, I publish.

I am a much happier developer after finding git and being able to manage my own changes and still be able to get upstream changes that I can rebase my stuff on.

I realize that this looks raw for end users, but I am my own end user.

If I would ship something to other end users I would look into using `.ez` zip archive files that the erlang code loader can use. See section "[Loading of Code From Archive Files](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/code.html)" on that page. Then provide a script that invokes erl with the correct arguments.

If the repository isn't available as a git, I git-svn clone it. If I can't do that, I tend to stay away from it.

Comment: These .ez files seem like a brilliant idea, rather like jar files in Java I guess, and is the type of thing I am looking for. Is there a .ez repository?

Comment: I was comparing the jar files to ez files in that they are both renamed zip files. Yes, you are correct, there is no jar repository, which was a shortcoming of Java in the early years which caused Maven to become so popular when it introduced a jar repository.

Comment: Also, I need things installed by non-technical people often, which excludes the use of git. Starting an Erlang shell is about the limit of their abilities usually :)

Comment: If their system is reasonably set up and they have an ERL_LIBS environment variable defined then you could just drop your .ez files there and erlang will find them automatically. No installation at all really. This will not work as well if you need to do some initialisation or start-up.

Answer (score 4):

I use faxien (a package manager for Erlang releases and applications) from the Erlware project: http://www.erlware.org. It and sinan are essential tools for Erlang development :).

Answer (score 2):

I use [Agner](http://erlagner.org/) on Mac, Linux, and Unix; and [CEAN](http://cean.process-one.net/) on Windows. CEAN's the only Erlang package manager with Windows support.

Comment: CEAN supports Windows, Mac, and Linux, by the way.

Answer (score 1):

I package them on a Debian repository on [Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/~jldupont).

Comment: I never heard of LaunchPad before. I went to the link you included but it is not obvious what launchpad does, or even how to add your libraries to my Erlang setup. I guess I need to install Debian to make use of it :)

Comment: You follow the instructions on page https://launchpad.net/~jldupont/+archive/jldupont to add the PPA to your Ubuntu `sources` and then just use `apt-get` as usual.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Just out of interest why did you add this PPA thing (which I had never heard of until now) and just do something like:

apt-get install APPNAME

?

Comment: I like the convenience of managed repository e.g. takes care of dependencies.

Comment: But canonical has their own "Canonical managed repository". Why not use that, or am I missing the point here?

Comment: Is this still valid? I would like that idea as it is usable on Debian based boxes. But what about other disros like say redhat? Can they still use ppa repos? Also, this means that an end user on windows or Mac could not use that package easily. That's why i like the idea of epm. I am coming from using php and node with npm so the idea is nice as it manages its own dependencies. Although i understand some dependencies may not be am Erlang package.